# Scan from dock?

Tags: scanning

If I want to scan, I need to open system preferences, click "Printers/Scanners", and select the scanner, to open the application. I'd like to click on an icon in the dock to open it. How to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the scanner application running, right-click in the Dock and select "Options->Keep in Dock".